# transfer normal website code to parse cloud

Tags: parse-platform

I have fully working website, which is developed with PHP & javascript. If I want to transfer it to parse cloud, Do I need to change whole (backend/ frontend) code for it? Please tell me the steps to follow. And how do I transfer mysql database to parse data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are General Steps, depends on the current website it may require more corrections/steps/polishing -

1. Create database equivalent to MySQL in Parse in terms of CLASSES/COLLECTION.
2. Create Cloud code methods equivalent to Serverside PHP methods.
3. Make changes in Client Side - for SERVICE/METHODS calls of PHP - to call PARSE Cloud Code Methods.
4. You have to put your Client side files in PUBLIC/ directory of PARSE Cloud Code.

Comment: My website already working very smoothly. If I want move to parse, I have to do lots of **rework/redevelopment of front-end and back-end**, I am right?

Comment: If your backend is about a ton then yes & for frontend - not much work if your application is properly modularized.